# Sort array of dictionaries based on key and value

Tags: swift, dictionary

Been playing around the [high order functions](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8) lately,
and i thought of a case and i don't know if this is even possible, 
consider the case below.

> **StringDictionary** - `typealias StringDictionary = [String: String]`

```
var Group: [StringDictionary] =  [
["Key1":"val2"],
["Key4":"val4"],
["Key3":"val3"],
["Key5":"val5"],
["Key2":"val1"],
]
```

I want to reorder this array of dictionaries to be like this.
**Expected Result**

```
 var Result =  [
    ["Key1":"val1"],
    ["Key2":"val2"],
    ["Key3":"val3"],
    ["Key4":"val4"],
    ["Key5":"val5"],
]
```

Using **High order functions**

Comment: You can sort the keys and then use that as a way to access your dictionary in a sorted fashion

Comment: yeah meant an array of dictionaries :)

Comment: Why is it an array of dictionaries and not a single dictionary?

Comment: Check updated ans

Comment: but if you use sort again you would, lose the first sort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typealias StringDictionary = [String: String]

var Group: [StringDictionary] =  [
    ["Key1":"val2"],
    ["Key4":"val4"],
    ["Key3":"val3"],
    ["Key5":"val5"],
    ["Key2":"val1"],
]
let keys = Group.map { Array($0.keys) }.reduce([String]()) { $0 + $1 }.sorted()
let values = Group.map { Array($0.values) }.reduce([String]()) { $0 + $1 }.sorted()
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))
let newGroup:[StringDictionary] = dict.map { [$0:$1] }.sorted{ $0.keys.first! < $1.keys.first! }
print(newGroup)
```

Comment: your answer was right check the expected result, add the sorting function you deleted using keys before values

Comment: @MohmmadS Do you want to sort both keys and values?

Comment: Yes please check question

Comment: and here we lost the key order ... this is the twist

Comment: I forgot to sort